# The set of associated primes are finite

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring and $M$ be a $R$ module.

Suppose the set of associated primes of a module $M$ is finite, then does it necessarily mean that the support of the module $M$ is closed?

Support of $M$ is defined to the set of the all primes $p$ such that $M_p\neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $R = \mathbb{C}[x]$ and $M = R_x$, the localization at $x$. Then (0) is the only associated prime of $M$, but Supp $M$ is Spec $R$ $\setminus V(x)$, which is open but not closed.